# Getting first n non-zero elements of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix M like this:

```
>>> M
array([[1, 0, 3, 4],
       [0, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 4, 0, 7]])
```

What I want to do is to extract is the first N (let's say N = 2) non-zero elements of each row in M and put them in a new matrix M2 of the same shape, while setting the matching values in M to zero. So the output should be:

```
>>> M
array([[0, 0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 7]])

>>> M2
array([[1, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 0],
       [5, 4, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Pretty bad practice on deleting your [`recent question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402589), specially given the time someone has given to attend to clearing up the deficiencies in the problem and then actually solve it. People would find less motivation to answer your questions given that behavior of deleting questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach with [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) -

```
M2 = M*((M!=0).cumsum(1)<=2)
M_new = M - M2
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: M
Out[42]: 
array([[1, 0, 3, 4],
       [0, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 4, 0, 7]])

In [43]: M2 = M*((M!=0).cumsum(1)<=2)
    ...: M_new = M - M2
    ...: 

In [44]: M_new
Out[44]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 7]])

In [45]: M2
Out[45]: 
array([[1, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 0],
       [5, 4, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: I really liked your reasoning ! Good job !