# Applying a function to every element in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function which calculates an adjusted cosine similarity between two elements, sort of like:

```
def sim(x,y,M):
    filtered = M[(M[:, x] > 0) & (M[:, y] > 0)]
    m = np.average(filtered, axis=1, weights=filtered.astype(bool))
    i = filtered[:, x] - m
    j = filtered[:, y] - m
    return np.sum(i * j) / (np.linalg.norm(i) * np.linalg.norm(j))
```

I also have a n*n matrix for which i want to get sim() for every pair, i.e. 0,0-n,n.
Currently I'm doing this using two for-loops which works well but it's pretty slow:

```
def get_matrix(M):
    new_mat = []
    for x in range(3):
        for y in range(3):
            new_mat.append(sim(x,y,M))
    return np.reshape(new_mat, (3,3))
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? M (*mn*) and mat (*nn*) don't have the same dimensions..

Edit:

My M looks like this:

```
[[   0.  100.  300.]
 [ 100.  200.    0.]
 [ 250.  150.    0.]
 [ 250.  200.    0.]]
```

And as output i want a matrix (new_mat) of size 3x3 in this case, which contains the similarities between each item, simplified:

```
[[  1.  -1.  -1.]
 [ -1.   1.  -1.]
 [ -1.  -1.   1.]]
```

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis` or `np.apply_over_axes`?

Comment: Shapes of `filtered`, `M`, `mat`?

Comment: The shape of mat is 792x792, M is 194x792 and filtered is Nx792 depending on what is being filtered

Comment: But you are using `weights=filtered`, so are you actually using a 2D array for the weights there?

Comment: Sorry, m is just N, depending on what's been filtered

Comment: Well your `filtered` is of different shape than M because of the masking. Could you verify that the sample inputs work with the code?

Comment: Yes, the 3x3 matrix is the output from my loop approach (though i changed two nan's to 0.). With a bigger dataset the -1 values range from -1 to 1.

Comment: I tried with a random (3,3) shaped array for `mat` and didn't work : `1D weights expected when shapes of a and weights differ.` at that line : `m = np.average(M, a...`, as I stated earlier.

Comment: I mixed some of my code up when I wrote the original post, but I've edited it and the code there should now work!

Comment: Are you actually testing it out before posting? :) Doesn't work yet.

Comment: Sorry! It definitely works now! I appreciate you taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's have it finally, as it turned out to be much more complicated than anticipated! So, here's a vectorized approach making use of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) at various places -

```
avg = M.sum(1)/((M>0).sum(1))
mask = M>0
subs = M - avg[:,None]

masked_subs = mask*subs
sums = np.dot(masked_subs.T,masked_subs)

comb_mask = mask[:,None,:] & mask[:,:,None] 
norm_i = np.linalg.norm(subs[:,:,None]*comb_mask, axis=0)
norm_j = np.linalg.norm(subs[:,None,:]*comb_mask, axis=0)
out = sums/(norm_i*norm_j)
```

Comment: Actually I got confused in my previous response, filtered is of size N*792 and m is of size N. filtered is M[(M[:, x] > 0) & (M[:, y] > 0)]

Comment: @Roadhouse I think it would make sense if you could add sample arrays for those three arrays. So, I guess you could use minimal arrays of say `mat` as `(4,4)`, `M` as `(3,4)` and similarly for `filtered`. Idea is to show us a minimal working sample that works with your listed codes and thus avoid all of those confusions from both sides.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I've updated the original post, hope that clarifies it a bit.